# Changing side of line numbering in two columns documents part two

Tags: listings, positioning, two-column, line-numbering

I have the same question as this one:
[tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/changing-side-of-line-numbering-in-two-columns-documents/](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/changing-side-of-line-numbering-in-two-columns-documents/)

I'd like to use the `listings` package in a `twocolumn` document. An option like `numbers=outside` would be awesome, but doesn't exist (yet?).

I tried the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@numpos\if\@firstcolumn left\else right\fi
\makeatother
```

and in `\lstset` I set `numbers=\@numpos`. It obviously doesn't work that way.

The first answer on the above-mentioned question is a neat solution, but simply does not do what I and the other question's author ask for. The presented solution has a flaw as well: the line numbers a ragged to the right (if `numbers=left`), I'd like it better if they were ragged to the left.

---

By the way / off topic:
I commented on the above-mentioned question, but my answer got deleted and I was advised to start my own question about it. Probably because my answer was not an actual answer, just another question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've defined a new option for `numbers`, called `outside`. It prints numbers in the left margin if you are on the left column and in the right margin if you are on the right column.

This is the relevant code:

```
\makeatletter
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont%
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}}\\%
     outside&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\if@firstcolumn%
                \llap{\normalfont%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}%
                \else%
                \rlap{\normalfont%
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}%
                \fi%
                }%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother
```

And this is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont%
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}}\\%
     outside&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\if@firstcolumn%
                \llap{\normalfont%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}%
                \else%
                \rlap{\normalfont%
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}%
                \fi%
                }%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

\lstset{numbers=outside,frame=tb,numbersep=1em,language=pascal}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
\end{lstlisting}

\newpage

\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

---

### EDIT

The following works fine with all sizes for standard classes, but it may need adjustments depending on your `\lstset` settings.

```
\newlength{\mylength}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont%
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}}\\%
     outside&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{%
                \setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}%
                \if@firstcolumn%
                  \ifdim\mylength>0pt%
                    \llap{\normalfont%
                    \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}%
                  \else%
                    \rlap{\normalfont%
                    \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                    \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}%
                  \fi%
                \else%
                  \ifdim\mylength>0pt%
                    \rlap{\normalfont%
                    \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                    \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}%
                  \else%
                    \llap{\normalfont%
                    \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}%
                  \fi%
                \fi%
                }%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\newlength{\mylength}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont%
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}}\\%
     outside&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{%
                \setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}%
                \if@firstcolumn%
                  \ifdim\mylength>0pt%
                    \llap{\normalfont%
                    \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}%
                  \else%
                    \rlap{\normalfont%
                    \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                    \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}%
                  \fi%
                \else%
                  \ifdim\mylength>0pt%
                    \rlap{\normalfont%
                    \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep%
                    \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}%
                  \else%
                    \llap{\normalfont%
                    \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}%
                  \fi%
                \fi%
                }%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

\lstset{numbers=outside,frame=tb,numbersep=1em,language=pascal}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you veeeeeeeery much! One issue: if the code spans multiple columns, the first line in the new column has a number on the left instead of right. Any idea what makes this happen of to fix this?

Comment: @Erik See the edit. If you still have problems, let me know what you have in your settings.

Comment: Great, now it works. I felt if `left` and `right` were options, `outside` should have been one too! The result is great, it looks better IMHO than left hand numbers with indented code. I like the code box the same size as the column text.